# Example from textbook: Missing opening tag on div element in return statement?

Tags: reactjs

I found this example in a textbook, but in the functional component's return statement
there is no opening tag on the div element. Is this possible?

```
function ColorList({ colors=[], onRemoveColor=f=>f}){
  if(!colors.length) return <div>No Colors Listed. (Add a Color)</div>;

  return (
    colors.map(color => (
    <Color key={color.id} {...color} onRemove={onRemoveColor} />
  ))
  </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: No, looks very much like a typo. Also, the `colors.map(...` should be in curly braces, not parenthesis, it isn't valid JSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```js
function ColorList({ colors=[], onRemoveColor=f=>f}){
  if(!colors.length) return <div>No Colors Listed. (Add a Color)</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      {colors.map(color => (
        <Color key={color.id} {...color} onRemove={onRemoveColor} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What text book is that?  Sounds like it needs a better editor.

Comment: Learning React, 2nd Edition, by Alex Banks, Eve Porcello

Comment: I learned a lot of my foundations from those 2 through their courses on Lynda.com.  I definitely recommend the courses on there if you can get access